# Jenkins with Xcode 8 - Cannot find Provisioning Profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, code-signing

Jenkins cannot find our recently updated provisioning profiles and after trying every known solution I'm running out of ideas what could be wrong.

Build jobs fail with error:

> No profile matching 'xxxxx' found: Xcode couldn't find a profile
>   matching 'xxxxx'.

The build server is a Mac, running Xcode 8 and we're using Jenkins with the Xcode plugin.

Building and signing with Xcode 8 directly on the same machine is successful and I installed all the required profiles by double-clicking them.

Does anyone know any workable solution to fix this issue?

Comment: Facing same issue recently. I hope someone posts this for Jenkins Jira.

Comment: trying https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52420 sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcscontrol /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcrun

Comment: That solved the No profile matching for me! (Now I get another error about PNG files). Please post as answer so I can mark as complete!

Comment: In my case, it was nothing to do with Xcode 8.  This was a better answer for me: http://code-dojo.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/fix-ios-code-signing-issue-when-using.html

Comment: @MikeM In my case Jenkins is on ubuntu and running mac laptop as slave so what will be solution for me

Answer (score 3):

Put your provisioning profiles under

#### User/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Mobile Device/Provisioning Profiles.

You have to create manually folder under Library folder.

And make sure that your Distribution certificate is in "System" tab in keychain Access. If not then copy from "Login" tab and paste under "System" tab.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for myself was giving the jenkins user proper permissions for the `~/Library/MobileDevice` folder and the `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profile`.

Otherwise the jenkins user can't read from the provisioning file folder.